# Spring Boot Dynamic field

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to handle the dynmaic fields creation in ui  and mapping it to the backend in the spring boot.
I have all the fields in the mysql  and data storage in mongo.
How to map with pojo entity to save and retrive.

I have tried with the pojo and without pojo mpaiings using spring jpa.

Comment: What do you mean by " I have all the fields in the mysql and data storage in mongo"? Do you mean the list of fields a user can choose from is in mysql, but the actual data storage is in mongo?

Comment: The form fields will be in the mysql schema and storing the data will be in other database.

Comment: It is not at all clear, what you are trying to do. Could you please give a concrete example? Also is this about mongodb or JPA?

Comment: It's with two database. One database will have table with all the field names as records ex:owner id, name, owner type. Same fields will be in my entity file. I will store the owner records in my mongodb. User  can add new field for the owner entity from ui. If new fields are added from front end I will store those fields in mysql field table. But newly created fields will not be in my entity poja class

Answer (score 0):

"dynamic" fields ? Do you mean adding columns on the flight?
This is looks like LOV (anti-)pattern that could be mapped to an entity (id, owner_id, key, value) where all values will be store as string, the key will be your field name, id an IDENTITY, and owner_id the FK on the other entity owning the set of (key, value).

Comment: Dynamic fields are created in th ui and stored in the mysql fields table. Some fields will not be in the entity pojo. How to handle those fields in storing retrieval.

Comment: As explained in my answer: you need another entity linked to the "owner" entity and storing the  (key, value) pairs. They are other ways too like using JSON or XML columns but they make searching more complicated.

Comment: I understand that. But in my case suppose I have owner entity with id, owner name, owner type these fields will be in the pojo entity , I can do crud operation on it. Now I amd adding status and phone number field from ui now this fields will not be in the entriy file but fields will be created in the mysql field table for the owner entity

Comment: So what's the problem? You have 2 @Entity with one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Why to create two entity, because new fields are created dynamicly in the runtime from ui

Comment: Because you don't know by advance how many dynamic fields you will have per owner entity, so you have to model a one-to-many relationship, so 2 @Entity.

Example:
owner_entity(id, name, type, ...)
 1, 'A', 'person', ...
 2, 'B', 'company', ...
 
dynamic_fields(id, ownerid, key, value)
 1, 1, 'phone', '123-456.78'
 2, 1, 'email', 'A@my.com'
 3, 2, 'phone', '456-789.123'
 4, 2, 'email', 'info@b.com'

Comment: Thanks, I understand bit now, can you give some example code. So I can understand in depth.

Answer (score 0):

you UI consume a rest api that returns a list of fields to display. Up to you to choose how to store it :
In a relational database, you need to have a principal table and a table that store the fields and then you can retrieve it by a join.
In a mongodb, you can have a document, the fields will be a part of it as a json array and then you can retrive it by parsing the json.

Is that you want to do ? The how depends on what framework you use (I see Spring) (So Spring data works both with a mongodb and a mysql)

Comment: Whether it's possible with spring boot entity class and data jpa